# Write out the Thue-Morse sequence

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence, binary

There's quite a few challenges on this site that ask you to print out a sequence, and this is no exception.

(The following explanation of the sequence for this challenge assumes the symbols in the sequence are `0` and `1`.)

The recursive definition of the [Thue-Morse sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%E2%80%93Morse_sequence) is that

```
T_0 = 0
T_2n = T_n
T_2n+1 = 1 - T_n
```

A more direct definition is that the sequence from `0` to `2**m-1` and `2**m to 2**(m+1)-1` are binary complements. So `0` is followed by `1`, `01` is followed by `10`, `0110` is followed by `1001`, and, skipping ahead a bit, `0110100110010110` is followed by `1001011001101001`.

The challenge is to write a program or a function that prints out the [Thue-Morse sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%E2%80%93Morse_sequence) for the first `n` elements, where `n` is any non-negative integer. The output can use any two symbols, as shown in the examples below.

**Examples**

```
>>> tm_01(20)
01101001100101101001
>>> tm_ab(42)
abbabaabbaababbabaababbaabbabaabbaababbaab
>>> tm_paren(37)
())()(())(()())()(()())(())()(())(()(
>>> tm_space_star(12)
 ** *  **  *
>>> tm_01(0)
                # to show that this is a valid input
```

**Rules**

- The input will be any non-negative integer. You can assume all inputs are valid.
- The output must be the first `n` elements of the Thue-Morse sequence, using any symbols that are convenient. If you like, you can also add a separator. In my examples, I have not.
  **Note:** This rule allows lists (like those of Python), as `,` is a valid separator and I don't mind leading or trailing characters, such as `[` and `]` in the output.
- This is code golf, so the smallest number of bytes wins.

As always, if the problem is unclear, please let me know. Good luck and good golfing!

### Catalogue

```js
var QUESTION_ID=65549;var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe";var COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk";var OVERRIDE_USER=47581;var answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=true,comment_page;function answersUrl(index){return"http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+index+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(index,answers){return"http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+answers.join(';')+"/comments?page="+index+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:true,success:function(data){answers.push.apply(answers,data.items);answers_hash=[];answer_ids=[];data.items.forEach(function(a){a.comments=[];var id=+a.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(id);answers_hash[id]=a});if(!data.has_more)more_answers=false;comment_page=1;getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:true,success:function(data){data.items.forEach(function(c){if(c.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER)answers_hash[c.post_id].comments.push(c)});if(data.has_more)getComments();else if(more_answers)getAnswers();else process()}})}getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,<]*(?:<(?:[^\n>]*>[^\n<]*<\/[^\n>]*>)[^\n,<]*)*),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/;var OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;function getAuthorName(a){return a.owner.display_name}function process(){var valid=[];answers.forEach(function(a){var body=a.body;a.comments.forEach(function(c){if(OVERRIDE_REG.test(c.body))body='<h1>'+c.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,'')+'</h1>'});var match=body.match(SCORE_REG);if(match)valid.push({user:getAuthorName(a),size:+match[2],language:match[1],link:a.share_link,});else console.log(body)});valid.sort(function(a,b){var aB=a.size,bB=b.size;return aB-bB});var languages={};var place=1;var lastSize=null;var lastPlace=1;valid.forEach(function(a){if(a.size!=lastSize)lastPlace=place;lastSize=a.size;++place;var answer=jQuery("#answer-template").html();answer=answer.replace("{{PLACE}}",lastPlace+".").replace("{{NAME}}",a.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",a.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",a.size).replace("{{LINK}}",a.link);answer=jQuery(answer);jQuery("#answers").append(answer);var lang=a.language;lang=jQuery('<a>'+lang+'</a>').text();languages[lang]=languages[lang]||{lang:a.language,lang_raw:lang.toLowerCase(),user:a.user,size:a.size,link:a.link}});var langs=[];for(var lang in languages)if(languages.hasOwnProperty(lang))langs.push(languages[lang]);langs.sort(function(a,b){if(a.lang_raw>b.lang_raw)return 1;if(a.lang_raw<b.lang_raw)return-1;return 0});for(var i=0;i<langs.length;++i){var language=jQuery("#language-template").html();var lang=langs[i];language=language.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",lang.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",lang.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",lang.size).replace("{{LINK}}",lang.link);language=jQuery(language);jQuery("#languages").append(language)}}
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="language-list"> <h2>Shortest Solution by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr> </thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr> </thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr> </tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr> </tbody> </table>
```

Comment: [Related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/24571/8478)

Comment: in simpler words you could say: the function is recursive, negate the input and append it.

Comment: @Eumel yeah, but that might give people too big a hint. I do want to see some variety in the solutions.

Comment: [Borderline dupe](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/10601/194)

Comment: @PeterTaylor In what way? One possible answer to the linked question is the Thue-Morse sequence, but this question is to generate the Thue-Morse and nothing else.

Comment: Well, I did say you could put separators in the sequence and the `, ` between list items is a separator. I'll allow it. Let me edit the question to indicate this. @ThomasKwa

Comment: Because some of the answers to the previous question can be used to answer this question with trivial changes, and all answers to this question can be used to answer the previous question with trivial changes.

Comment: Do they have to be single symbols, or will any two easily distinguishable non-empty strings work?

Comment: @SuperJedi224 That's a good point. Any two distinguishable non-emergency strings are alright

Comment: Does it have to be `1` and `0`, or can `a` and `b` work?

Comment: @EasterlyIrk You are allowed to used any two distinguishable non-empty strings, including `a` and `b`.

Comment: @Sherlock9 okay, thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Pyth, 6 bytes

```
xMjR2Q
```

Try it online: [Demonstration](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=xMjR2Q&input=20&debug=0)

Based on the solution from @ThomasKwa and a variation of @FryAmTheEggman.

It uses the following formular: the `i`-th digit in the Thue-Morse sequence is: `xor(digits of i in base 2)`.

#### Explanation:

```
xMjR2Q   implicit: Q = input number
  jR2Q   convert each number in [0, 1, ..., Q-1] to its binary digits
xM       xor each binary list
```

Answer (score 9):

### CJam, <s>17</s> 9 bytes

```
ri{2b:^}/
```

or

```
ri,2fb::^
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q~%7B2b%3A%5E%7D%2F&input=42)

#### Explanation

This uses the alternative definition given on Wikipedia, based on the parity of the number of `1`s in the binary representation of the `n`.

```
ri   e# Read input and convert to integer n.
{    e# For each i from 0 to n-1...
  2b e#   Convert i to base 2.
  :^ e#   Fold XOR over the bits to compute the parity of the number of 1s.
}/
```

The alternative solution uses `,` to turn `n` explicitly into a range `[0 ... n-1]` before using infix operators to compute the binary representations and the XOR without needing a block.

#### Bonus Solutions

Here are some solutions based on other definitions. If there are two solutions, the shorter one will blow up memory *very* quickly (because the precomputation generates `2^n` bits before truncating to `n`).

As an L-system with `0 --> 01` and `1 --> 10`:

```
ri_2mL2,\{2,aA+f=s:~}*<
ri_2,\{2,aA+f=s:~}*<
```

By negating and appending the previous part:

```
ri_2mL2,\{_:!+}*<
ri_2,\{_:!+}*<
```

Using the recurrence relation given in the challenge, using `divmod` and XOR to distinguish between the two recursive definitions:

```
ri{Ta{2md\j^}j}/
```

(Although, of course, this recurrence relation is just a different way to express the Thue-Morse sequence as the parity of the 1-bits in the binary representation of `n`.)

Comment: The memory-wasteful solution was my first thought as well, but I figured using over half a terabyte of memory to compute the output for `42` (assuming a bitset) would be pretty unreasonable.

Comment: @JohnE Problem solved. ;)

Comment: `:^` makes me happy. On another note, holy crap, that's a cool algorithm.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes not `:^}`?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder That makes me happy too

Answer (score 8):

## LabVIEW, 15 [LabVIEW Primitives](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7589/39490)

now as super fancy gif with a probe

[image]

Comment: Could you explain how this would be tested?

Comment: option 1: get labview test version and rebuild it, Option: suggest a way how i can send this to you as .exe or .vi (for the latter you have to get labview as well)

Comment: Really I would just like to see how this behaves when it runs. Would recording a GIF be illustrative?

Comment: that a great idea i just did that and will up it in a sec

Answer (score 8):

### Dyalog APL, <s>8</s> 7 bytes

```
≠⌿⍴∘2⊤⍳
```

This is a monadic train that expects an index origin of 0 (`⎕IO←0`). The equivalent non-train function is `{≠⌿(⍵⍴2)⊤⍳⍵}`.

Explanation:

```
      ⍳      List of numbers from 0 to (input-1)
  ⍴∘2        (input) copies of 2
     ⊤       Convert all the elements in ⍳ to base 2 to (input) digits
≠⌿           Reduce over the first axis by not-equal
```

Output is a space-separated list of `0` and `1`. Try it [here](http://tryapl.org/?a=%u2395IO%u21900%u22C4%28%u2260%u233F%u2374%u22182%u22A4%u2373%29%A80%201%202%203%205%208%2013&run).

Answer (score 8):

## Mathematica, <s>35</s> 21 bytes

Mathematica has a built-in for the Thue-Morse sequence!

```
Array[ThueMorse,#,0]&
```

---

Original answer:

```
#&@@@DigitCount[Range@#-1,2]~Mod~2&
```

Answer (score 6):

### J, <s>12</s> 11 bytes

@MartinBüttner saved a byte.

```
~:/@#:"0@i.
```

This is a monadic (meaning unary) function, used as follows:

```
   f =: ~:/@#:"0@i.
   f 10
0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0
```

### Explanation

I'm using the alternative definition that T<sub>n</sub> is the parity of the number of 1-bits in the binary representation of n.

```
~:/@#:"0@i.  Input is n.
~:/          Output is XOR folded over
   @#:       the binary representations of
      "0     each element of
        @i.  integers from 0 to n-1.
```

Comment: `{.(,-)^:]` works for 9 bytes with some rule stretching ([which has been allowed](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/26320284#26320284)). E.g. for `5` it outputs `5 _5 _5 5 _5`. (Added only as a comment because of the rule stretching.)

Answer (score 4):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/Japt), <s>29</s> 11 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
Uo ®¤¬r@X^Y
```

[Try it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=VW8grqSsckBYXlk=&input=NDI=)

Outputs directly as an array, which saves about 4 bytes.

#### Ungolfed and explanation

```
Uo ®   ¤  ¬ r@  X^Y
Uo mZ{Zs2 q rXY{X^Y}}
        // Implicit: U = input number
Uo      // Create an array of integers in the range `[0, U)`. 
mZ{Zs2  // Map each item Z in this range to Z.toString(2),
q rXY{  //  split into chars, and reduced by
X^Y}}   //   XORing.
        //  This returns (number of 1s in the binary string) % 2.
        // Implicit: output last expression
```

**Edit:** You can now use the following **8-byte** code (not valid; feature published after this challenge):

```
Uo ®¤¬r^
```

Comment: you might want to update your explanation

Comment: @Eumel I already did...?

Comment: the code you explain and the code above look different

Comment: @Eumel There, is that better?

Comment: thats perfect :)

Answer (score 4):

### Pyth, <s>11</s> 10 bytes

```
m%ssM.Bd2Q
```

Outputs as a Python-style list.

Comment: I tried using XOR over the binary string, but I don't know nearly enough about Pyth to do that. This is much shorter anyway. +1

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Ah, I didn't know about `F` because I searched for 'reduce'. You could post as CW...

Answer (score 4):

### Haskell, <s>39</s> <s>36</s> 35 bytes

```
take<*>(iterate([id,(1-)]<*>)[0]!!)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcixDkAwEADQ3VecxNCKJtUY8SNluFRLo2i03@9Yje9tmHYbArlhooy77euR@WxvzJZpvzSsFXz@kms5lyWnA/0JAyxXARBvf2aowEGrflTyx04V9BgXcE0kTIwv)

How it works: start with `[0]` and apply the `x ++ invert x`-function `n` times. Take the first `n` elements from the resulting list. Thanks to Haskell's laziness only the first `n` elements are actually calculated.
Note: the first `<*>` is in function context, the second in list context.

With GHC v8.4 (which wasn't available at the the time of the challenge) there's a 34 byte solution:

```
take<*>(iterate(id<>map(1-))[0]!!)
```

Edit: -3 resp. -4 bytes thanks to @Laikoni. -1 byte thanks to  @Ørjan Johansen.

Comment: `(\x->x++map(1-)x)` can be shortened to `([id,(1-)]<*>)` or `(id<>map(1-))` with GHC 8.4.

Comment: `take<*>(iterate([id,(1-)]<*>)[0]!!)`

Answer (score 4):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 33 bytes

```
n->[sumdigits(x,2)%2|x<-[0..n-1]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/ifpmD7P0/XLrq4NDclMz2zpFijQsdIU9WopsJGN9pATy9P1zA29n9BUWZeiUaahrGRpuZ/AA)

Answer (score 3):

## K5, <s>27</s> 13 bytes

```
{x#((log x)%log 2){x,~x}/0}
```

Calculating the sequence is pretty easy, the problem is avoiding computing too much. We can recognize that the easy expansion of the sequence gives us a sequence of strings which are successive powers of two in length. Taking the log base 2 of the input and rounding up will give us enough to work with and then we can cut it down to the appropriate size:

```
  {x#((log x)%log 2){x,~x}/0}'(20 42 37 12 0)
(0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1
 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1
 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0
 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1
 ())
```

### Edit:

A parity-based solution:

```
~=/'(64#2)\'!
```

In action:

```
  ~=/'(64#2)\'!20
0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1
```

Note that since K5 doesn't have an arbitrary convert-to-binary primitive I have to specify, for example, a 64-bit decoding. K5 doesn't use arbitrary precision math, so there will be a limit to the size of inputs we can deal with in any case.

Answer (score 3):

## Octave, <s>33</s> 31 bytes

Saved 2 bytes thanks to Thomas Kwa.

```
@(n)mod(sum(dec2bin(0:n-1)'),2)
```

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, 54 bytes

Less compact than nimi's solution, but I did not want to deny you this piece of functional code obfuscation. Works for any pair of objects; e.g. you can replace `(f 0.f 1)` by `(f 'A'.f 'B')`.

Based on the definition that the first 2<sup>n</sup> digits are followed by the same sequence of digits inverted.
What we do is build up two lists side-by-side; one for the sequence, one for the inverse. Continuously we append increasingly long parts of one list to the other.

The implementation consists of three definitions:

```
t=(f 0.f 1)t
f c=flip take.(c:).g 1
g n l=l n++g(n+n)l
```

Function `t` accepts any number and returns the Thue-Morse sequence of that length. The other two functions are helpers.

- Function `f` represents either list; `f 0` is for the sequence, `f 1` for the inverse.
- Function `g` takes care of appending increasingly long repetitions of one list to the other.

Fiddle: http://goo.gl/wjk9S0

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 9 bytes

*This language was designed after the challenge*.

### Approach 1: 13 bytes

This builds the sequence by concatenating negated copies of increasing-size blocks.

```
itBFw"t~h]w:)
```

#### Example

```
>> matl itBFw"t~h]w:)
> 20
0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1
```

#### Explanation

```
i           % input number, say "N"
tB          % duplicate and convert to binary. Produces a vector
F           % initialize sequence to "false"
w           % swap to bring vector to top
"           % for loop. There will be at least log2(N) iterations
  t~h       % duplicate, negate, concatenate
]           % end for
w           % swap
:)          % index with vector 1, 2, ..., N
```

### Approach 2: 9 bytes

This uses the same approach as [Alephalpha's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/65612/36398).

```
i:1-B!s2\
```

#### Example

```
>> matl i:1-B!s2\
> 20
0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1
```

#### Explanation

```
i           % input "N" 
:1-         % create vector 0, 1, ..., N-1
B           % convert to binary
!           % tranpose
s           % sum
2\          % modulo 2
```

Answer (score 2):

### Burlesque, 21 bytes

```
{0}{J)n!_+}400E!jri.+
```

Examples:

```
blsq ) "20"{0}{J)n!_+}400E!jri.+
{0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1}
blsq ) "42"{0}{J)n!_+}400E!jri.+
{0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1}
```

Explanation:

```
{0}      -- setup
{J)n!_+} -- duplicate, map invert, concatenate
400E!    -- do 400 times (this will eventually run
            out of memory).
jri.+    -- take n elements
```

Without the `jri.+` part you will run out of memory (because it will compute the morse sequence of length *incredibly huge number*). But since Burlesque is lazy just asking for the first n-element will work anyway.

Comment: Nice. Similar to my Haskell solution. However, I repeat only 99 times to save one byte.

Answer (score 2):

## , 11 chars / 23 bytes (non-competitive)

```
Ⓐïⓜ_ⓑⓢĊ⇀$^_
```

<kbd>[Try it here (Firefox only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter.html?eval=true&input=5&code=%E2%92%B6%C3%AF%E2%93%9C_%E2%93%91%E2%93%A2%C4%8A%E2%87%80%24%5E_)</kbd>

The circles are strong with this one.

Answer (score 2):

## Perl 5, <s>62</s> 49 bytes

Yeah, not the best language for this one, but I still like the way it came out. Requires 5.14+ for `/r` and `say`.

```
sub{$_=0;$_.=y/01/10/r while$_[0]>length;say substr$_,0,$_[0]}
```

Using the parity definition, requires 5.12+ for `say`:

```
sub{say map{sprintf("%b",$_)=~y/1//%2}0..$_[0]-1}
```

Answer (score 2):

## C, <strike>88</strike> 83 bytes

Calculates the parity for each individual position.

```
i,j;main(int c,char**a){for(;i<atoi(a[1]);putchar(c))for(c=48,j=i++;j;j&=j-1)c^=1;}
```

Fiddle: http://goo.gl/znxmOk

Answer (score 2):

### [Retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina), <s>70</s> 69 bytes

Using the definition as an L-system with initial word `0` and productions `0 --> 01` and `1 --> 10`.

```
^
0;
(T`d`ab`^(.)+;(?!(?<-1>.)+$)
a
01
)`b
10
!`^(?=.*;(.)+)(?<-1>.)+
```

Input is taken [in unary](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5343/can-numeric-input-output-be-in-unary).

You can run the code from a single file with the `-s` flag. Or just [try it online.](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=XgphCihUYGFiYEFCYF4oXEQpKzEoPyEoPzwtMT4uKSskKQpBCmFiCilgQgpiYQohYF4oPz1cRCooLikrKSg_PC0xPi4pKw&input=MTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTEx)

#### Explanation

```
^
0;
```

Prepends `0;` to the input, where `0` is the initial word and `;` is just a separator.

```
(T`d`ab`^(.)+;(?!(?<-1>.)+$)
```

The `(` indicates that this is the beginning of a loop (which repeats until the loop stops changing the string). This stage itself turns `0` and `1` into `a` and `b` respectively (because `d` expands to `0-9`). It does this as long as current word (whose length is measured with `(.)+` is shorter than the input (i.e. as long as we can't read the end of the string by matching as many `1`s as we have in the word).

```
a
01
```

Replace `a` (stand-in for `0`) with `01`.

```
)`b
10
```

Replace `b` (stand-in for `1`) with `10`. This is also the end of the loop. The loop terminates once the condition in the transliteration stage fails, because then all `0`s and `1`s will remain unchanged and the other two stages won't find anything to match.

```
!`^(?=.*;(.)+)(?<-1>.)+
```

The last step is to truncate the word to the length of the input. This time we measure the length of the input with `(.)+` in a lookahead. Then we match that many characters from the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 2):

## Prolog (SWI), 115 bytes

**Code:**

```
N*X:-N>1,R is N//2,R*Y,X is(N mod 2)xor Y;X=N.
p(N):-M is N-1,findall(E,between(0,M,E),L),maplist(*,L,K),write(K).
```

**Explained:**

```
N*X:-                                 % Calculate Thue-Morse number at index N
     N>1,                             % Input is bigger than 1
     R is N//2,R*Y,X is(N mod 2)xor Y % Thue-Morse digit at index N is binary digits of N xor'ed
     ;X=N.                            % OR set X to N (end of recursion)
p(N):-
      M is N-1,                       % Get index of Nth number
      findall(E,between(0,M,E),L),    % Make a list of number 0->N-1
      maplist(*,L,K),                 % Map * on list L producing K
      write(K).                       % Print K
```

**Example:**

```
p(20).
[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
```

Try it online [here](http://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/HhUAESEr.pl)

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 33

```
->n{n.times{|i|p ("%b"%i).sum%2}}
```

Call like this:

```
f=->n{n.times{|i|p ("%b"%i).sum%2}}
f[16]
```

Uses the fact that the parity of binary numbers forms the thue-morse sequence.

Separator character is newline. Converts number `i` to a binary string, then calculates the sum of all ASCII codes, modulo 2.

If newline is not an acceptable separator, the following has no separator for an additional 2 bytes:

```
->n{n.times{|i|$><<("%b"%i).sum%2}}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
ḶB§Ḃ
```

Note that this challenge is older than Jelly.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjm1Oh5Y/3NH0//9/EyMA)

#### How it works

```
ḶB§Ḃ  Main link. Argument: n (integer)

Ḷ     Unlength; yield [0, ..., n-1].
 B    Compute the binary representation of each integer in the range.
  §   Take the sum of each binary representation.
   Ḃ  Take the LSB of each sum.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Common Lisp](http://www.clisp.org/), 50 bytes

```lisp
(lambda(n)(dotimes(i n)(princ(mod(logcount i)2))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcdLEoAgCADQfadgCTvrRuanYQbBUs9Pvt1LwqM7jjJfqI4S250jKmG2ya0MZNjpH2vCZhnFnmRLJzBdtDkdWJemKAIVzhDIfw)

Answer (score 2):

## [V (vim)](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), <sup><s>35</s></sup> 29 bytes

```
C0<esc>qqy$V!tr 01 10
P|q@-@q@-lD
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/39nAJrU42a6wsFIlTLGkSMHAUMHQgCugptBB1wGIc1z@/zcy@K9bBgA)

-6 bytes from Leo.

Prints the first \$n\$ elements.

The sequence is basically a string replacement and append, so it does that \$n\$ times using `tr` and then truncates the sequence to \$n\$ digits.

Comment: Nice one, here's how to get it shorter :) [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/39nAJrU42a6wsFIlTLGkSMHAUMHQgCugptBB1wGIc1z@/zcy@K9bBgA "V (vim) – Try It Online")
Main trick is the use of `@-` (from [this tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/94335/62393)), then `C` is equivalent to `Di`, the `:` in `V:!` is superfluous, and I've played around with the copy-paste-move to avoid the need for `gJ`

Comment: @Leo nice golfs.

Answer (score 1):

## Matlab, 42

I am using the fact that it is the same as beginning with `0` and then repeating the step of appending the complement of the current series, `n` times.

```
t=0;for k=1:input('');t=[t;~t];end;disp(t)
```

Comment: You can replace the disp(t) by t I think...

Answer (score 1):

## [Arcyóu](https://github.com/nazek42/arcyou), <s>50</s> 55 bytes

*I had to add 5 bytes to get it to work correctly :(*

```
(f i(_(#(l)))(r b^(@(> i 0)(pg 0(% i 2)(: i(#/ i 2))))0
```

Explanation (with Pythonesque pseudocode along the side:

```
(f i (_ (# (l)))       ; For i in range(int(input())):
  (r b^                ; Reduce with binary xor
    (@ (> i 0)         ; While i > 0:
      (pg 0            ; Return first of its arguments
        (% i 2)        ; i mod 2
        (: i (#/ i 2)) ; i //= 2
      )
    )
    0                  ; Default reduce argument of 0 for the first bit in the sequence
```

Answer (score 1):

### Bash, <strike>71</strike> 66 bytes

Based on the definition that the first 2<sup>n</sup> digits are followed by the same sequence of digits inverted.

```
x=0;y=1;while((${#x}<$1));do z=$x;x=$x$y;y=$y$z;done;echo ${x::$1}
```

`$1` as a parameter is the desired number of digits.

Fiddle: http://goo.gl/RkDZIC

Answer (score 1):

### Batch, 115 + 2 = 117 bytes

Based on the Bash answer.

```
@echo off
set x=0
set y=1
set z=0
:a
set x=!x!!y!
set y=!y!!z!
set z=!x:~0,%1!
if !z!==!x! goto a
echo !z!
```

Needs an extra `/V` in the invocation to allow the use of `!`s.

Answer (score 1):

### ES6, 53 bytes

```
f=(i,x="0",y=1)=>x.length<i?f(i,x+y,y+x):x.slice(0,i)
```

Recursion seemed simpler than a loop.

Answer (score 1):

## [Par](http://ypnypn.github.io/Par/), 8 bytes

```
✶u[Σ_✶¨^
```

Explanation:

```
✶          parse implicit input number
 u         range [0..n-1]
  [        map:
   Σ           convert to binary
    _✶         get digit list
      ¨^       fold with xor
```

Outputs something like:

```
(0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Math++](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Math%2B%2B), 86 bytes

Uses `0.0\n` for 0 and `1.0\n` for 1

```
?>n
3*!!(n-m)>$
m>a
0>k
6+6*!a>$
9-2*!(a%2)>$
a/2>a
5>$
(a-1)/2>a
!k>k
5>$
k
m+1>m
2>$
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 6 bytes

```
moF≠ḋŀ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/Pzff7VHngoc7uo82/P//38gAAA)

### Using infinite list:

```
↑¹!¡S+m¬;0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HbxEM7FQ8tDNbOPbTG2uD///9GBgA)

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, <s>84</s> <s>80</s> 60 bytes

Since nobody else was using characters other than `0` and `1`, I decided to write my own answer. Here, I use the characters `o` and `t`, but I was quite tempted to use `b` and `o`, or `p` and `o` :P

This is a parity checker in 60 bytes.

```
lambda n:''.join("ot"[bin(i).count("1")%2]for i in range(n))
```

This is a string rewriting algorithm in 109 bytes.

```
def t(n):
 r="o";s=""
 for i in range(len(bin(n))):
  for c in r:s+="otto"[c>"o"::2]
  r=s;s=""
 return r[:n]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://github.com/ngn/k), 16 bytes

```
{2!+/'(x#2)\'!x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/z/NqtpIUVtfXaNC2UgzRl2xovZ/moKJ0X8A)

Comment: I think `{2!+/(x#2)\!x}` works for the non-zero inputs, potentially saving two bytes.

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
╩0ΔΔ(
```

[Run and debug it at staxlang.xyz!](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=ca30ffff28&i=20%0A42%0A0%0A37%0A12&a=1&m=2)

#### Unpacked (6 bytes) and explanation:

```
mv:11I
mv        Map block over range [0,n):
  :1        Popcount
    1I      Is odd?
            Implicit print with newline
```

`1I` is bitwise and with 1. `2%` would work just as well, also packing to 5 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 43 bytes

```
def f(n):n>0==f(n-1);print(n.bit_count()%2)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3tVNS0xTSNPI0rfLsDGxtgSxdQ03rgqLMvBKNPL2kzJL45PxSIFtT1UgTomVpmoaRAZQNMwYA)